# Preventing abusing of load and stress testing software like JMeter

Tags: linux

I tried JMeter a couple of days ago to stress and load test my local web server just to try it out and see how it worked. But it looked like I could do that to any server as long as I have the ip address. Or maybe I don't even need the ip address maybe the url is enough I'm not sure. Is it that easy to abuse it and make other peoples websites slower by sending alot of requests to them? And also how do I prevent something like this if someone decides to overload my servers on purpose. Do I use iptables on linux to block their ip address? Also what kind of software could I use to set up an alarm thing so that I don't have to monitor it all the time manually. Or maybe software that blocks ip automatically. Sorry about too many question I'm just trying to understand how one would go about fixing an issue like this, "the general procedure or routine" if you will.

Comment: Try to google `DDoS monitoring tool` or `DDoS mitigation`. There are plenty of software solutions for this kind of problems. Unfortunately, a professional attacker would not flood you from a single IP address but use a botnet of remotely controlled PCs, which is much harder to block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct.  A standard load testing tool can most certainly be used maliciously to cause Denial of Service (DoS), or even Distributed DoS if enough remote hosts are used.  However, they tend to be less effective than a real DoS tool like Low Orbit Ion Cannon *(I wouldn't even download LOIC unless you want to be on some kind of watch list).*

Most enterprise companies will pay for DDoS "prevention" services, such as those offered by [Prolexic](http://www.prolexic.com)  *(I'm not in any way affiliated, just happen to know of this provider).*  Prevention is quoted because nobody can stop a DDoS attack, rather they have enough capacity to handle it.

In terms of running your own small Web Server, you may get the level of protection you need by carefully configuring IPTABLES.  There are ways to specify TCP limits per IP to prevent large bursts in traffic.  Check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437059/linux-command-to-prevent-dos-attack-by-using-netstat-and-iptables) out for more information.

-AA Ron

Comment: Thanks for the tips that was useful!